# linked list that represents a number

Tags: java, linked-list

I have an IntNode class that looks like this:

```
public class IntNode {
private int value;
private IntNode next;
public IntNode(int val, IntNode n)
{
    value = val;
    next = n;
}
public void setValue(int val){ value = val; }
public void setNext(IntNode n){ next = n; }
public int getValue() { return value; }
public IntNode getNext() { return next; }
}
```

and another class that I named it BigNumber which should represent any positive number (big or small). The class looks like:

```
public class BigNumber {

private IntNode list;
    //copy constructor.
public BigNumber(BigNumber other){
    list = null;
    for(IntNode p=other.list; p!=null; p=p.getNext())
        list = new IntNode(p.getValue(), list);
}

    //Constructor that takes string of a number and puts every digit in the linked list. if the string contains any char that is not digit, the linked list should be: 0->null.
public BigNumber(String num){
    list = null;
    if(stringIsNum(num)){
        for(int i=0; i<num.length(); i++){
            list = new IntNode((int)num.charAt(i),list);
        }
    }
    else{
        list = new IntNode(0, list);
    }
}

private boolean stringIsNum(String num){
    for(int i=0; i<num.length(); i++){
        if(!(num.charAt(i)>='0' && num.charAt(i)<='9'))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(IntNode p=list; p!=null; p=p.getNext())
        s+=p.getValue()+"";
    return s;   
}
}
```

The problem in this class is that when I want to print, lets say the string is "123", it prints something like 515049 instead of the actual number which is 321, (it should print the number backwards).
What is the problem?

Comment: This means that it's time to learn to use a debugger as this should 1) help you find the answer yourself, and 2) give you insight into how to use a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting char's to int. This gives the codepoint of the char, not the value you want. eg: (int) '1' = 49

Instead of `(int)num.charAt(i)` use `Integer.parseInt(num.charAt(i))`

Answer (score 1):

You *are* getting 321.  51, 50, and 49 are the char values for 3, 2, and 1.  Your code is saving the char values and not the actual values.  In other words, you're close, and just need to save the right values.